# Ajax multiple divs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax code which show more details in 1 Div .. my question is how to show ajax in two or three divs ?

```
    function GetDetails(id)
    {
        $(document).ready(one);
        function one()
        {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else { 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Micrososft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState ==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
        document.getElementById('tv'+id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        }
        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'ajax.php?c='+id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        var thebutton = '#button'+id;
        $(thebutton).hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to break results in more divs or do you want to get values of more divs?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, as you seem to be, why don't you just use [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Comment: I have 2 kind of data I want to show them in different divs not one.

Comment: @DaveRandom I don't want any data from the same document. I need the file ajax.php echo some data in different divs. For instance, div_right and div_bottom each one will update after the function called.

Comment: You need to separate the way the data is returned by the server, so you make 3 separate Ajax requests. So for example `'ajax.php?c='+id+'&div=1'` will return the data for div 1, and `'ajax.php?c='+id+'&div=2'` will return the data for div 2. Then you can just do `$('#div1').load('ajax.php?c='+id+'&div=1')` and `$('#div2').load('ajax.php?c='+id+'&div=2')`

Comment: @DaveRandom ** thank you so much work's fine now** so the JQuery is better than Ajax or what ? because my code now become 4 lines only LOL

Comment: @OthmanAbahossain It is better in that is it easier to write (like you say, it's now only four lines) and it is likely to be more cross-compatible. If any newer browsers come out that break you Ajax code then all you need to do is use an updated jQ library, rather than rewriting all your code - that's sort of the point of jQ!

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that SURELY won't be in your output, separate the things you want to separate IN THE PHP CODE, then in JS, use either `xmlhttp.responseText.split` or PHPJS.org's `[explode()][1]` and if there is no such thing, then you perhaps should make sure there WILL be. Somehow, for example, with `str_replace()` in PHP.

Or, alternatively, if you have enough bandwith, send more than one request.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest, fastest and also 'best practice' way is as follows:

Assuming you are using jquery and you have multiple divs, say two, that looks like this

```
<div id="tv1More"> 
    We need to add this div somewhere...
</div>
<div id="tv2More">
    and this one somewhere else (with 1 ajax call!)
</div>
```

First, put another div anywhere on your page that is hidden by default

```
<div id="receiver" style="display:none;"> 
</div>
```

Then change your line

```
document.getElementById('tv'+id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

to one that updates two divs as follows:

```
//Put the retrieved HTML into the DOM 
$("#receiver").html(xmlhttp.responseText); 
$(document.getElementById('tv'+1)) //Select the div that needs to be updated
    .html($("#tv1More").html()); //and update the first div
$(document.getElementById('tv'+2)) //and also
    .html($("#tv1More").html()); //the second div
```

I have not actually tested the above code so there could be typos.

It is usually better to use a single ajax call since it will considerably improve the time the page takes to load.